# How to generate a column of checkboxes from a list

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I recently found **PySimpleGUI**.  At the time looked like it could save me a lot of work.

I wanting to create a 'tagger' for jpeg images using PySimpleGUI as the interface.

I have a long list of tag-words in a simple python list.

I have had some success as I can create a row of checkboxes, but not a column.

My initial research found a generator to use to make many checkboxes.
My goal is to have 3 columns filled with list generated chackboxes.

#### Generator Snippet

I found this snippet of code to generate the buttons from this PySimpleGUI [page.](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)  Then modified for checkboxes.  I have working functions, but I can't format the construct them to a column.

```
def CBtn(BoxText):
    return sg.Checkbox(BoxText, size=(8, 1), default=False)

column2 = sg.Column([[sg.Text('User Id:')], [CBtn(Bx) for Bx in Tags1]])
```

#### Main Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('Dark Red')
TaggerList = ["viking", "saddle", "beast", "ze", "princess", "vet", "art", "two", "hood", "mosaic",
              "viking1", "saddle1", "beast1", "ze1", "princess1", "vet1", "art1", "two1", "hood1", "mosaic1"]

TaggerListLen = len(TaggerList)
Tags1 = TaggerList[:int(TaggerListLen/3)]
Tags2 = TaggerList[int(TaggerListLen/3):int(TaggerListLen/3*2)]
Tags3 = TaggerList[int(TaggerListLen/3*2):]


def CBtn(BoxText):
    return sg.Checkbox(BoxText, size=(8, 1), default=False)

column2 = [[sg.Text('Column 2', justification='center', size=(10, 1))], [CBtn(Bx) for Bx in Tags2]]

column5 = sg.Column([[sg.Checkbox("BoxText1", size=(8, 1), default=False)],
            [sg.Checkbox("BoxText2", size=(8, 1), default=False)],
            [sg.Checkbox("BoxText3", size=(8, 1), default=False)],
            [sg.Checkbox("BoxText4", size=(8, 1), default=False)]])

layout = [
    [sg.Menu(menu_def, tearoff=True)],
    [sg.Text('Image Tagger', size=(
        30, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 25), relief=sg.RELIEF_RIDGE)],
    [sg.Text('Your Folder', size=(15, 1), justification='right'),
        sg.InputText('Default Folder'), sg.FolderBrowse()],
    [sg.Column(column2)]
    [column5]

window = sg.Window('Everything bagel', layout)
```

Shown in the screen capture the generated checkboxes are set in a row and not a column.  So `sg.Column(column2)` is a row.  When I manually add the checkboxes for `column5` I get a proper column.

[image: Screen_Capture]

#### Format

When I use the generator definition I get this: `[CBtn('1'), CBtn('2'), CBtn('3'), CBtn('log'), CBtn('ln'), CBtn('-')],`

I'm looking for something like this: `[[CBtn('1')], [CBtn('2')], [CBtn('3')], [CBtn('log')], [CBtn('ln')], [CBtn('-')]],`
As this follows the manual **column5** format.

I've have tried many variations of the generator and `def` without much success.
Here is an example of my attempts to achieve the format above.

```
column1 = [[sg.Text('Column 1', justification='center', size=(10, 1))], [BaseTag.append([CBtn(Bx)]) for Bx in Tags1]]
```

But I get a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ParentContainer'

#### Final

This was suppose to be easy.  I guess, I'm bending the framework too much.
PySimplegui looked good, but after hours of no head way, I wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, mass production of objects can only be done in a simple loop.
Modifications to the code:.
1. [[CBtn(i)] for i in range(len(Tags2))]
2. 'column2' and 'column5' were changed to 'column2' and 'column5' respectively.
3. added in 'layout' as there are no commas or brackets; column2)], column5]]

```
def CBtn(BoxText):
    return sg.Checkbox(BoxText, size=(8, 1), default=False)

col2 = [[CBtn(i)] for i in range(len(Tags2))]

col5 = sg.Column([[sg.Checkbox("BoxText1", size=(8, 1), default=False)],
            [sg.Checkbox("BoxText2", size=(8, 1), default=False)],
            [sg.Checkbox("BoxText3", size=(8, 1), default=False)],
            [sg.Checkbox("BoxText4", size=(8, 1), default=False)]])

layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_def, tearoff=True)],
    [sg.Text('Image Tagger', size=(
        30, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 25), relief=sg.RELIEF_RIDGE)],
    [sg.Text('Your Folder', size=(15, 1), justification='right'),
        sg.InputText('Default Folder'), sg.FolderBrowse()],
    [sg.Text('Column 2', justification='center', size=(10, 1))],
    [sg.Column(col2)],
    [col5]]

window = sg.Window('Everything bagel', layout)
```

Comment: This almost works.   I needed to update the generator slightly to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This almost works. I needed to update the generator slightly to get what I wanted. 
The column gernated only had numbers.  I needed to add the keywords.

Modified code:

```
column1 = [[CBtn(Tags1[i])] for i in range(len(Tags1))]
```

Then the column is populated with the values from the list.
Now on to how more easy this frame is.